# How to get the complete systems info( like memory, drives, serial number and more) in a network using core ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How to get the complete systems info( like memory, drives, serial number and more) in a network using core ruby for both linux as well windows machines.

Could you please suggest the gem or the way to do this.

Thanks
Vam.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if gem for this exist but ruby has good support for invoking system commands. You can invoke any unix command just by putting reverse quotes. For instance (assume that this code located in some .rb file):

```
puts `vmstat`
```

will print system information about memory usage. Same will work for the windows. Commands (if exist) will be different though.